# How to connect to other computer on same network without ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, administrator

I am trying to visit each computer on my local network via the command line on an Ubuntu system. I would like to do things like administer files and update configurations. How is this done?  Also is there a software tool I can install on each system that will allow me to remote in and make changes? I do not want to use SSH or Telnet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you expect from people when you mention nothing about what do you want or why `I do not want to use SSH or Telnet.`?

Comment: Agree with @TomYan -  SSH is the tool designed to do this - why do you not want to use it and what eactly are you trying to achieve.  Many (most?) decent tools that help with maintenance will use SSH as  an underlying mechanism.   There are also tools like ansible/puppet/salt - but these are not appropriate in the context of "remoteing in" - they are designed for mass deployments.  RDP and VNC are desktop sharing protocols you may want to look at if you want to work on the desktop.  (Of-course, ssh -X will allow you to log in to the remote server and forward a window back...)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use SSH, you can install XRDP on Linux machines:

> Install xrdp: `sudo apt install xrdp`
>
> Enable xrdp: `sudo systemctl enable xrdp`
>
> Start the xrdp service (must be started each time computer is restarted):
> `sudo systemctl start xrdp`

Then you can access the Linux computer with RDP.  I have done this and it works fine.